# Getting access to the metaclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to better understand the rules of Ruby and how to get access to the metaclass. I'm reading Yehuda Katz's article on metaprogramming and I came across this:

```
matz = Object.new  
def matz.speak  
  "Place your burden to machine's shoulders"
end

matz.class #=> Object
```

In fact, matz's "class" is its invisible metaclass. We can even get access to the metaclass:

```
metaclass = class << matz; self; end  
metaclass.instance_methods.grep(/speak/) #=> ["speak"]
```

What is going on on this line:

```
metaclass = class << matz; self; end
```

Is that the same as:

```
matz
   self
end
```

?

Comment: note: `matz.singleton_methods #=> [:speak]`

Comment: I'm perplexed that the method [Object#singleton_class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) is not used more. That allows us to write `metaclass = matz.singleton_class`. I think you'll agree that that's more readable than `metaclass = class << matz; self; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on on this line:
>
> ```
> metaclass = class << matz; self; end
> ```

```
class << foo
```

opens the singleton class of `foo`. Inside a class definition body, `self` is the class. The return value of a class definition body is the value of the last expression inside the class definition body.

So, we assign the value of the class definition body, which is the value of the last expression inside the class definition body, which is `self`, which is the class, i.e. the singleton class of `matz`.

In other words: we assign the singleton class of `matz` to the local variable `metaclass`.

Note that modern Ruby has the [`Object#singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) method for that purpose (added in Ruby 1.9.2, released in 2010).

> Is that the same as:
>
> ```
> matz
>    self
> end
> ```

Obviously not, since the former is legal syntax, and this isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`class << matz; self; end` is equivalent to

```
class << mats
  self
end
```

`class << matz; end` opens the singleton class (Ruby official name of metaclass). It is also an expression that returns the return value of the last expression that is evaluated inside it, in this case, `self`.

I think you are familiar with `self` since you are playing with metaprogramming. The `self` refers to the class itself when it's in the scope of a class, in your code, it refers to the singleton class.

P.S. starts from Ruby 1.9.2, there's no need to use this shovel syntax to grab a singleton class. Just `obj.singleton_class`.